# why "life" bother to exist when its literally just a bunch of atoms and particles?

Tags: existence, existentialism

There is no meaning to existence. It exists, and it disappears, everything in our perception will one day disappear, the world will end or the human race will end.

The “You” means nothing to existence. We are just a lumpy pile of matter that learned to rearrange other matters for their own benefit.

Your friends, family, they too are nothing. Just necessary bonds to your host for survival. There is nothing to the world. Everything, emotions, marvel, beauty,  happiness, love, shock and pain, all came from “You”. From “your” perspective, the little chemicals in your brain dictates all that you feel and comprehend, as it was apparent through discoveries in the biology field.
You must realize, there is absolutely nothing greater out there. No point to live, that is unless if you are religious and believe in an afterlife, which I meant absolutely no offence if this did. Life itself is a mishap. There is no point to its existence. Just convenient matter that happened to be able to stay together.

This is reality, where all “your” actions literally mean nothing at all. All “your” achievements, all that “you” love and “own”, is nothing. Existence doesn’t care. Existence is itself. Existence continue on without your opinion.

Its funny how people chases the small things in “life”. The price for a meal, the joy of watching make-believe movies, reading make-believe stories. Love. Fun. “You” are not getting anything out of that. Its all just “you”. “We” communicate to “ourselves”, saying how a tiny part of existence changed to “their” liking or mourn.

Yet, even knowing this, its impossible to escape this reality. It exists, and so did “you”. Its everything. “I” still feel sadness. “I” still feel excitement typing these words. “I” am a “useless” man. “I” know that. “Usefulness” all depends on the thoughts of “your” “matter”, at which I still am not.

“I” can see poets writing about love, singers on stages live for their crowds, “me” thinking about how to type in here. Why would we do that, when everything else is nothing?

After all, all that “we” can think about is “us” and even more of “us”, “our” offsprings will will probably continue on thinking the same thing, until the day that we all die and be forgotten. Until that day, we are still stuck in our small community on Earth, arguing about the latest stock changes and the price of oil.

Its harsh. I know that, I felt that. 
That is why I chose to ignore it. I chose to ignore my very own philosophical opinion.

Since there is nothing to nothing, which is meaningless, I might as well make myself think that there is something to exist for. The matter in me, when together they can feel joy, a concept that is enjoyable to me. I can feel the joy of others, and in turn I too feel joy. When I succeed in my tasks others and I set myself, I feel triumphant, even though it is ridiculously pointless to existence.When I post this somewhere on the internet, I will feel anticipation, hope.

I will let myself enjoy the “ignorance”, for now. My biological will to survive wants me to continue on to survive despite know the idiocy of life, and maybe to read other’s opinion on this. We are just so “We”, self-centered. Its impossible to feel anything other than what we perceive as “living”.
Sometimes, maybe ignorance is happiness. Ignorance is bliss, and so I heard and confirmed.

My question is, after/even knowing that there is ultimately no point in existing since we will never achieve anything except for ourselves or accept the fact that we are too small to comprehend how self-centered we are, why do we still go back to our normal, everyday lives, or simply stop bothering about our own existence?

Comment: the anticipation and hope that you may feel now after posting this nice prose will be short lived; soon the law and order-loving policemen of this website will come along and close this post as inappropriate for this "Q&A" website... and will probably delete this comment as well, which will then cease to exist, becoming nothing at all once again...

Comment: Not really a question - just a wall of text.

Comment: @user 16825 Could you please edit your text and state a few theses, each with an argument why you consider the thesis to be correct. Please extract then one or two questions from your text and state them explicitly in one sentence. I assume this philosophical blog always asks for arguments.

Comment: You might be interested in reading Kierkegaard, Sarte, and other existential thinkers. You might also enjoy the lighthearted comedy of the movie I <3 huckabees.

Answer (score 5):

I find it amazing that you are just 14 years old; you sound a little like Marvin the Paranoid Android, and even if you only have a brain half the size of his, I am getting high on just contemplating what wonders might occur if you dive into some books of philosophy, math and physics...

---

I mean, maybe the universe has no meaning but it is also fantastically beautiful and mind blowing.

If you study math you could discover an equation as beautiful as Euler's identity: [image]

If you study physics, you could discover something mind blowing about the universe, like Einstein, Feynman, Maxwell and so many others.

If you study philosophy, you could share with us an amazing insight about human consciousness,

> I stand at the seashore, alone, and start to think.
>
> There are the rushing waves, mountains of molecules
>   Each stupidly minding its own business
>   Trillions apart, yet forming white surf in unison.
>
> Ages on ages, before any eyes could see
>   Year after year, thunderously pounding the shore as now
>   For whom, for what?
>   On a dead planet, with no life to entertain.
>
> Never at rest, tortured by energy
>   Wasted prodigiously by the sun, poured into space.
>   A mite makes the sea roar.
>
> Deep in the sea, all molecules repeat the patterns
>   Of one another till complex new ones are formed
>   They make others like themselves
>   And a new dance starts
>
> Growing in size and complexity
>   Living things, masses of atoms, DNA, protein
>   Dancing a pattern ever more intricate
>
> Out of the cradle onto the dry land
>   Here it is standing
>   Atoms with consciousness,
>   Matter with curiosity
>
> Stands at the sea,
>   Wonders at wondering: I,
>   A universe of atoms
>   An atom in the universe
>
> -- Richard Feynman

Comment: I consider your text more a comment than an answer. Which question did you extract from the text and which is your answer to this question?

Comment: I enjoy your answer, upvote +1